# SonarQube Dashboard shows - Pending analysis for more than two days

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

SonarQube Server Environment details as follows:

```
• SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.7 (64-Bit). 
• Operating System: Ubuntu-16.04 –LTS.
• MYSQL Database Version - 5.7.21
• Database Current Size: 16-GB
```

**Problem:**
All our builds getting finished successfully on our Jenkins, However on SonarQube dashboard for each build it shows –Pending.(There is a pending analysis, More details available on the Background tasks page). Whereas if I move to `Corresponding project`--> `Administration` --> `Background tasks` --> `Logs`. Location here I don’t say see any errors. This problem started last couple of weeks onwards only.  No change on the server side.

I have tried the following.

```
1)  Rebooted the SonarQube Server and then cleared the $SONAR_HOME/data/es folder
2)  Also cleared $SONAR_HOME/temp/ folder.
3)  Then started the Sonarqube service.
```

But still same problem. Let me any other around to fix the same.

Comment: What do you see when on the global Background Tasks page? (Look in global Administration... under Projects, IIRC.)

Comment: Under Global Administration-->Projects-->Background Tasks i could see many projects status shows pending. for one project it is showing -In-progress. that project log as follows.

Comment: 2018.03.28 04:45:36 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AWJk9c2BOWyQU4tWHYdQ
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o Date of analysis cannot be older than the date of the last known analysis on this project. Value: "2018-03-10T12:59:06+0530". Latest analysis: "2018-03-21T06:27:17+0530". It's only possible to rebuild the past in a chronological order.
2018.03.28 04:45:36 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.scm.voma | type=REPORT | id=AWJk9c2BOWyQU4tWHYdQ | submitter=mohan.s | time=478ms

Comment: can you delete that task?

Comment: yes deleted already, Now latest analysis is in-progress. Hopefully it will work this time.

Comment: Thanks, post cancelled the running task, now results uploading perfectly. thanks a lot for quick support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As resolved in comments, analysis report processing was blocked in your instance by an erroring analysis report. It seems to have gotten hung in an errored-but-still-processing state and by hogging the background task processor, it was blocking all other background tasks, i.e. it was blocking completion of all subsequent analyses.

The way to resolve this error is to remove the blocking task: Global **Administration > Projects > Background Tasks** & delete the problem task.